# How to parse 20180810T143000Z to time_t

Tags: esp8266, c, time

What is the shortest/most elegant way (i.e. use existing lib functions) to parse a string in the form of `20180810T143000Z` to a `time_t`? Note that the literal always represents a UTC timestamp.

I started parsing the string and assigning values to a `struct tm *tm` in order to do a `mktime(tm)` at the end. That feels overly complicated, though.

Comment: Which time library do you use? I would copy each needed character with an array index to a buffer and convert it to year, month, day, hours, minutes. After that I would use the library to convert that into a time_t for the number of seconds since 1970. Straightforward is not overly complicated in my opinion. Can you show what you have so far? sscanf might work, but some think that is not a elegant function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing the string really is the only way. However there are many ways of doing it.

My preferred method is to first check that the format is correct, by looking for the T and Z being in the right place:

```
if (timeString[8] == 'T' && timeString[15] == 'Z') {
    ... parse in here
}
```

And the parsing is just making numbers with multiplication:

```
int year = (timeString[0] - '0') * 1000 +
           (timeString[1] - '0') * 100 +
           (timeString[2] - '0') * 10 +
           (timeString[3] - '0');
```

You can clean things up with a macro if you like:

```
#define NUM(off, mult) ((timeString[(off)] - '0') * (mult))
```

Then:

```
int year =   NUM(0, 1000) + NUM(1, 100) + NUM(2, 10) + NUM(3, 1);
int month =  NUM(4, 10)   + NUM(5, 1);
int day =    NUM(6, 10)   + NUM(7, 1);
int hour =   NUM(9, 10)   + NUM(10, 1);
int minute = NUM(11, 10)  + NUM(12, 1);
int second = NUM(13, 10)  + NUM(14, 1);
```

And then, yes, put them in a `struct tm` (or directly assign them calculation results without using the intermediate variables) and call `mktime()`.

Comment: @Juraj Yeah, but you haven't included any answer in your answer, only a block of code ;)

Comment: "first check that the format is correct" - a valid point but what would you do in the `else` branch?

Comment: I can't tell you that. It depends on the rest of your program. The answer may be "nothing", or it may be "tell the user", it "request a new timestamp", or any number of other things.

Comment: @Majenko sorry, I was a little unspecific. I'm still getting familiar with Arduino (as you can tell). What I meant was that in most other environments/platforms I'm familiar with I'd probably throw an exception. So, I believe returning -1 and handle this outside the function will make this more robust.

Comment: @MarcelStör Sure - if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <Time.h>

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  char buff[] = "20180810T143000Z";
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buff); i++) {
    buff[i] = buff[i] - '0';
  }
  int yr = buff[0] * 1000 + buff[1] * 100 + buff[2] * 10 + buff[3];
  if (yr > 99)
    yr = yr - 1970;
  else
    yr += 30;
  TimeElements tm;
  tm.Year = yr;
  tm.Month = buff[4] * 10 + buff[5];
  tm.Day = buff[6] * 10 + buff[7];
  // 8 T
  tm.Hour = buff[9] * 10 + buff[10];
  tm.Minute = buff[11] * 10 + buff[12];
  tm.Second = buff[13] * 10 + buff[14];

  time_t t = makeTime(tm);

  sprintf(buff, "%02d%02d%02d %02d%02d%02d", year(t), month(t), day(t), hour(t), minute(t), second(t));

  Serial.println(buff);

}

void loop() {

}
```

You can install TimeLib in Library Manager. It works on all Arduino platforms.

Comment: Yep, I did look into `strptime` but concluded it would probably not work w/o delimiters. Therefore, I didn't even try.

Comment: In `buff[i++] * 10 + buff[i++]`, the order of evaluation of the `i++` is unspecified. It may work as expected with any particular combination of compiler version and settings, and fail on the next one. gcc 5.4 warns me that “operation on ‘i’ may be undefined”. The correct way to do that is `tm.Month = buff[i++] * 10; tm.Month += buff[i++];`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet thanks, I just proposed this change: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38715

Comment: @MarcelStör, I read Edgar's comment, but this code is not some snippet, but a complete working example. I don't like edit it without testing. And I can't test it now.

Comment: @MarcelStör: What I wrote for `tm.Month` is valid for every instance where `i++` appears more than once in the same expression.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I know, makes total sense. That's why proposed that edit. In the end it was ok to get rejected because many more lines are actually affected.

Comment: in this case the use of i++ is good. the compiler has no reason to evaluate some subexpression with i++ later in expression before some subexpression with i++ earlier in expression. I will change it. I saw the warning, but I had limited time for this.

Comment: Re “the compiler has no reason to evaluate [...]”: it also has no reason to evaluate them in the order you expect! Please, learn about sequence points in C++ before making such wrong assumptions. Note specifically that “Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.”

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another way to convert the time stamp string to time_t. There are several great answers here already, but you may want to compare binary file sizes. This sketch's is 3884 bytes (IDE Version 1.0.6.2, GCC 4.2.1).

```
#include <Time.h>
TimeElements myTimeElements;
char timeString[] = "20180810T143000Z";

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  myTimeElements.Year = CalendarYrToTm((timeString[0] - '0') * 1000 + (timeString[1] - '0') * 100 + (timeString[2] - '0') * 10 + (timeString[3] - '0'));
  myTimeElements.Month = (timeString[4] - '0') * 10 + (timeString[5] - '0');
  myTimeElements.Day = (timeString[6] - '0') * 10 + (timeString[7] - '0');
  myTimeElements.Hour = (timeString[9] - '0') * 10 + (timeString[10] - '0');
  myTimeElements.Minute = (timeString[11] - '0') * 10 + (timeString[12] - '0');
  myTimeElements.Second = (timeString[13] - '0') * 10 + (timeString[14] - '0');

  // Assemble time elements into time_t.
  time_t t = makeTime(myTimeElements);

  // Print out the contents of "t" one "piece" at a time using the "time_t" functions.
  Serial.println(year(t));
  Serial.println(month(t));
  Serial.println(day(t));
  Serial.println(hour(t));
  Serial.println(minute(t));
  Serial.println(second(t));

}

void loop(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness here's my "answer" working with `String`s rather than `char[]`.

```
time_t convertToTime(String calTimestamp) {
  struct tm tm;
  Serial.println("Parsing " + calTimestamp);
  String year = calTimestamp.substring(0, 4);
  String month = calTimestamp.substring(4, 6);
  if (month.startsWith("0")) {
    month = month.substring(1);
  }
  String day = calTimestamp.substring(6, 8);
  if (day.startsWith("0")) {
    month = day.substring(1);
  }
  tm.tm_year = year.toInt() - 1900;
  tm.tm_mon = month.toInt() - 1;
  tm.tm_mday = day.toInt();
  tm.tm_hour = calTimestamp.substring(9, 11).toInt();
  tm.tm_min = calTimestamp.substring(11, 13).toInt();
  tm.tm_sec = calTimestamp.substring(13, 15).toInt();
  return mktime(&tm);
}
```

Comment: That poor poor heap. I feel for it...

Comment: This should work, but note that every call to the `substring()` method allocates a new String on the heap. Even if you have plenty of free memory, the multiple calls to `malloc()` and `free()` can make this quite inefficient.

Comment: @EdgarBonet yes, I know, point taken. What is fed into this function is the (partial) result of an HTTP response `readStringUntil()`. I guess it'd be more efficient to first convert `calTimestamp` into a `char[]`?

Comment: Quite likely. The String method `c_str()` returns the internal `char *` pointer, so no real conversion is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not complete without sscanf.

I took the sketch by @Juraj and declared seperate integers to be sure that every %d would match with an integer.

```
#include <Time.h>

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  char buff[] = "20180810T143000Z";

  TimeElements tm;

  int yr, mnth, d, h, m, s;
  sscanf( buff, "%4d%2d%2dT%2d%2d%2dZ", &yr, &mnth, &d, &h, &m, &s);

  tm.Year = yr - 1970;
  tm.Month = mnth;
  tm.Day = d;
  tm.Hour = h;
  tm.Minute = m;
  tm.Second = s;

  time_t t = makeTime(tm);

  sprintf(buff, "%02d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", year(t), month(t), day(t), hour(t), minute(t), second(t));

  Serial.println(buff);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Marcel Stör, there are now four good solutions. In my opinion they are equally good.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to my first answer would be to use standard C functions from time.h and sscanf. C function strptime can't parse the timestamp without delimiters. But sscanf can parse your input.

```
#include <time.h>

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  const char* buff = "20180810T143000Z";

  tm tms;
  sscanf(buff, "%04d%02d%02dT%02d%02d%02d", &(tms.tm_year), &(tms.tm_mon), &(tms.tm_mday), &(tms.tm_hour), &(tms.tm_min), &(tms.tm_sec));
  tms.tm_year -= 1900;
  tms.tm_mon -= 1;
  tms.tm_isdst = 0;
  time_t t = mktime(&tms);

  Serial.println(ctime(&t));
}

void loop() {
}
```

In AVR "%02hhd" must be used because the corresponding members in struct tm are int8_t.

Comment: The %d is for an integer, also for an avr microcontroller. The difference is that the TimeLib TimeElements does not use integers, but bytes.

Comment: @Jot, this is C time.h

Comment: Yes, for the C time.h the tm_year and other elements are all integers. Also for a avr microcontroller the %d matches an integer. The %d expects an 'int', not a 2 or 4 byte variable.

Comment: %d on AVR works for sprintf, but sscanf read wrong without hh. try it

Comment: I tried it in a number of different ways with different data on the stack, using arduino 1.8.5 with arduino uno board. A 'int' is two bytes, a 'short int' is also two bytes and 'short short int' does not exist. Format "%d" works with a 'int', and "%hd" seems to do the same as the "%d". Format "%hhd" reads a signed byte. Everything is as I remember it, no weird things. If you can prove that you are right with a sketch, can you start a new topic for that?

Comment: @Jot, it is only when I use the tm struct members as sscanf parameters. The warning is '%d' expects argument of type 'int*', but argument 4 has type 'int8_t* {aka signed char*}'. and the scanned values are wrong. With regular int variable the hh is not needed.

Comment: AVR has `int8_t          tm_hour`

Comment: Now I see it, the tm for avr has int8_t and int16_t elements. Sorry, they are indeed not all integers for avr. I did not know that. Thanks. Do you agree that %d in sscanf matches 'int' for avr? I see that you have removed that confusing last sentence.

Comment: I used hh because a compiler warning saying that it is int8_t and it helped to get correct data. I opened time.h, but it was for samd or for esp and there was int. I had limited time so I didn't investigate it further than. Of course %d is for int. I tested int and removed the note. Then I discovered that in tm really is unt8_t in tm.

Answer (score 0):

```
String datetimestr = "20180810T143000Z";
int splitted = datetimestr.indexOf("T");
String datestr = datetimestr.substring(0, splitted); //20180810
String timestr = datetimestr.substring(splitted + 1, datetimestr.length() - 1); //143000
```

Comment: The question was how to parse the string **to a `time_t`**, and you are not answering it.