# ESP8266 ISO 8601 string to tm struct

Tags: esp8266, c++, time

I have a web service that returns timestamps in ISO 8601 format, e.g., `"2021-06-25T12:00:00"`
I'm trying to turn the timestamp string into a tm type struct from the ESP8266 library `<time.h>`, to perform time calculations using the `difftime()` function.

I've been referring to the Redhat time functions https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#time, as it seem to be compatible with the ESP library, though all i can find are functions converting tm structs to timestamp strings. Are there any functions to convert a string timestamp into a tm struct and then back into epoch? Or what would be the best way to approach this kind of conversion on the ESP8266 platform?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse 20180810T143000Z to time\_t](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55248/how-to-parse-20180810t143000z-to-time-t)

Comment: Thank you! This method works too, though i find the answer below to be more useful.

Comment: sorry yes, there is a different format. strptime can't parse a timestamp without delimiters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `strptime` from the `time.h`.

```
void setup()
{
    
  struct tm tm = {0};
  char buf[100];
  
  // Convert to tm struct
  strptime("2001-11-12 18:31:01", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
  
  // Can convert to any other format
  strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d %b %Y %H:%M", &tm);
  Serial.printf("%s", buf);
}

void loop()
{
    yield();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The method above works. I just formatted my string as `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"`,instead.